# Where does MacVim send its printed files?

Tags: macvim, printing

I found out about printing using the `:hardcopy` command, and on my Mac it opens up the output in a PDF named "0.pdf", then the next printing from that file opens "1.pdf", etc.

I can save these files, of course, but I'm wondering: Where are these files stored on disk?  Is there a setting which controls it somewhere?

I haven't been able to find the output files anywhere, including checking `/tmp`.  Appreciate any tips in the right direction.

---

`:set printexpr?` yields `system('open -a Preview '.v:fname_in) + v:shell_error`

The PDF viewer can't be made to show the file as being anywhere.  All usual methods for finding where the currently open file is aren't working at all.

Comment: Where does your PDF viewer show them as being located?

Comment: The `printexpr` setting should be used for this; so using `:set printexpr?` might yield some useful information?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I updated the question with the answers to your and muru's questions.

Answer (score 4):

I found it using `lsof`:

```
/private/var/folders/cr/jsb8dl_50lbdy05hj7v2l9wr0000gn/T/com.apple.Preview/PreviewTemp-79NyiU/0.pdf
```

And then I found the other files alongside it using `find`:

```
find /private/var/folders/cr/jsb8dl_50lbdy05hj7v2l9wr0000gn/T/com.apple.Preview -type f
```

I still don't know *why* it was put here, but at least I found it.

Comment: You could have found it by dragging the icon in the title bar to a terminal window.

Comment: @romainl, indeed!  Usually right click on the icon will show the parent directories, but not in this case.  Dragging did the trick and is much faster than `lsof`; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From [`:help pexpr-option`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/print.txt.html#pexpr%2doption):

> Expression that is evaluated to print the PostScript produced with
>   `:hardcopy`.
>   The file name to be printed is in `v:fname_in`.

It's a bit of a hack, but you can simply `echo` the `v:fname_in` variable to a file:

```
:let &printexpr = "system('echo '.v:fname_in.'>> /home/martin/hardcopy')"
```

And then examine the created hardcopy file, I found that on my Linux system it's `/tmp/vVLcfMS/6`, which indeed looks like a postscript file with the contents of my buffer ;-)

For OS X you probably want to use a path like `/Users/Wildcard/hardcopy`...

Pretty sure there's an easier way than this in OS X somehow, unless Saint Jobs the Magnificent decided that this was somehow not required for his petty mortal users (would not surprise me)... In any case, it's a useful lesson in basic "printf debugging" ;-)